# how to call Sequence function from SQL into Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a port 'Number_1' in expression transformation in Informatica. I connected the Number_1 port to a target sql table. 
I need to generate number for this port 'Number_1' every time i run the mapping starting from 1 till 999. once it reaches 999 then again the value of the Number_1 should reset to 1. I'm aware there is sequence generator trans. but i need to call Sequence function from SQL server. how to achieve above?

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure in sql server then use stored procedure tranformation to call this from Informatica

Answer (score 0):

You may call it using `Stored Procedure` transfomation. You may also use a stored procedure as SQL Override on `Source Qualifier`, however...

I hope you know what you're doing, as this is in general a very bad idea. Each call requires communication between Intergration Service and database - this will cause huge delays. Therefore it's much better to use Informatica's `Sequence Generator` or - even better perhaps, if all you need is an integer port with round robin - a simple expression variable.

Answer (score 0):

While maciejg says makes a lot of sense performance wise - however I've known a fair few people who were more comfortable using the native database sequencer than the inbuilt one ( even some Informatica specialists ).

The thing with Informatica sequencer is how much flexibility they give and when they get set wrong it can lead to unexpected numbers being picked.

One example I have is for a sequencer being used to create unique keys in a table - if you persist the value between sessions then it works fine until you select the incorrect option while reimporting the mapping.

If you choose to lookup your previous ending value from a config file / table and add the value produced by the sequencer to this then one day when someone by mistake sets the sequencer to persist values between runs you'll all of a sudden skip that many numbers in the sequence each time the session is restarted. Native db sequencers are very basic making them very predictable and fool proof